# Pooling on peak times start slowing my page and server. How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js

**What I do:** I save each page title, url, and time spent, visited by each visitor in my website. Other than that, every 5 seconds I send an update of the time spent on the specific page.

**How I do it:** I use a JSON that sends the data to "api.php" file which then saves the data into the database.

**What is my problem?** I noticed that on peak times, where I have a huge amount of visitors, things start to get slow.

My question is, how can I prevent this? Does this require me to re-write the code with a newer technology? If yes, which?

Comment: If you can't modify the requirements of the code (instead of every 5sec -> 30sec for instance) and your code is optimized (Share your code if you're not sure regarding this one), maybe consider hardware improvement?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I can change it from 5 secs to 30. Also, I send data when people leave the page or close the tab. However they do not tend to stay for 30 secs in a page, and when the page is unload, i noticed that I lose a lot of requests.

Comment: Where do you save the data? In a SQL database?

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos I am saving the data into mySQL

Comment: You can cache the data temporary and save them to the database in groups (every 1 min or every 5 mins), if the main problem is the mySQL overhead. You can try a difference methods for this, ex using a NoSQL database and then every 5 mins updating the SQL database may be faster.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos I sent you an email, please read it